# Functions and arrays which allows you to print what's the most repeated number

Tags: c

I have a problem with my code, it doesn't print the result I expect. This code allows the user to enter as many numbers as he wishes and then print the most repeated one

Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reading_numbers(int array[]){
int i = 0;
int Max = 0;
printf("How much long the array will be?\n");
scanf("%d", &Max);
while (i < Max) {
    printf("Insert the numbers\n");
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    i++;
}
}

void most_present_number(int array[], int Max){
int i = 0;
reading_numbers(array);
int current_number = array[i];
int current_number_count = 0;
int most_present_one = 0;
int most_present_one_counter = 0;
while (i < Max) {
    if (array[i] == current_number) {
        current_number_count++;
        i++;
    } else {
    if (current_number_count > most_present_one_counter){
        most_present_one = current_number;
        most_present_one_counter = current_number_count;
    }
    current_number_count = 1;
    }
}
printf("This is the most present number %d it is repeated %d times\n", most_present_one, 
most_present_one_counter);
}

int main() {
int Max = 0;
int array[Max];
most_present_number(array, Max);
return 0;
}
```

The problem for me is when I call the function, but I don't know how to fix it

I should have written as a premise but I'm a bit new to C so probably there are some things in this code that don't make sense

Comment: Why ask the length of array in `reading_numbers` if you're passing it as an argument?

Comment: How can an array have a size of `0` if you don't resize it?

Comment: I would suggest getting it working with a hard-coded array size first, and then introduce the added complication of variable length.

Comment: whatever value you are reading into `Max` in `reading_numbers`, does not reflect in `most_present_number`

Comment: what is `vettore`, its not declared anywhere in code.

Comment: `vettore` is the Italian way of saying `array`. My fault

Comment: As for the other comments, I understand what you are saying but I don't know how to do these things

Comment: Can you print value of `Max` in `reading_numbers` after `scanf` and in `most_present_number` after the call `reading_numbers` ?
do you see it is the same as you entred in `reading_numbers`?

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990  Such a declaration of a variable length array int Max = 0;
int array[Max]; is forbidden. The array may not have zero elements. So the program does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Mh, ok, so what's the value that i have to put in the square brackets?

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 At first you should ask the user to specify the number of elements of the array and after that declare the array with the specified number of elements provided that the number is positive.

Comment: In your loop, you must _always_ increment `i` on each iteration. Use: `for (; i < Max; ++i)` and eliminate the `i++` that is under the `if`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've done that in the `reading number` function

Comment: @IrAM Mh, ok, so these are two completely different things. Is there a way to "pass" the value of the `Max` variable found in the` reading_numbers` function to the other `Max` variable?

Comment: since you are making `Max` as 0 at the beginning and that is not valid , you can either define a macro like `#define MAX 10` and use in all places where you want to use `Max` or read in the `main` program it self and pass the value

Comment: @IrAM So there are no other ways to "pass" the read values from one function to another, right?

Comment: you can either by `return` ing the variable or passing address of variable from one function to other. if you have still more doubts you can ask one more question.

Comment: @IrAM How could i pass the value from the main?

Comment: as shown in below answer

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care)   1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces,

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  It is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @user3629249 I put it in my compiler. I'll edit the question and add it here as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a procedure to find the result ,int main() must have the size of array (mistake logic),because the procedure take the parameters of the main function (int main ())

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void most_present_number(int Max,int T[Max])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Max)
    {
        printf("Insert the numbers :");
        scanf("%d", &T[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    int k=0,cpt1=0,cpt=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<Max;i++)
    {
        cpt=0;
        for(int j=i+1;j<Max;j++)
        {
            if(T[i]==T[j])
            {
                cpt++;
            }
        }
        if(cpt>=cpt1)
        {
            cpt1=cpt;
            k=T[i];
        }
    }
    printf("This is the most present number %d it is repeated %d times\n",k,cpt1+1);
}

int main()
{
    int Max = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("How much long the array will be?\n");
        scanf("%d", &Max);
    }while(Max<1);
    int T[Max];
    most_present_number(Max,T);
}
```

Comment: @IrAM Sorry for the mistake

Comment: you can also handle for inputs like  1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @MEDLDN Thanks for the answer, but if possible I would like the number reading operation to be stored in another function

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 , no you can't make what you want because the function should takes their parameters from the main function (int main ())

Comment: It is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing: `#include<math.h>`

Comment: @MEDLDN What does cpt mean?

Comment: @Sub0Zero1990 cpt is the number of existence of each number (T[i]) in the array

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. only includes header files those contents are actually used

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reading_numbers( int Max, int array[ Max ][2])
{       
    for( int i = 0; i < Max; i++ ) 
    {
        printf("Insert the numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i][0]);
        array[i][1] = 0;
    }
}

void most_present_number( int Max, int array[ Max ][2] )
{   
    for( int i=0; i < Max; i++ ) 
    {
        for( int j=i; j<Max; j++ )
        {
            if ( array[i][0] == array[j][0] ) 
            {
                array[i][1]++;
            } 
        }
    }

    int most_present_one = array[0][0];
    int most_present_one_counter = array[0][1];
    
    for( int i=1; i<Max; i++ )
    {
        if( most_present_one_counter < array[i][1] )
        {
            most_present_one = array[i][0];
            most_present_one_counter = array[i][1];
        }
    }
        
    printf("This is the most present number %d it is repeated %d times\n", 
            most_present_one, 
            most_present_one_counter);
}


int main( void ) 
{
    int Max = 0;
    printf("How much long the array will be?\n");
    scanf("%d", &Max);
    
    int array[Max][2];  // uses variable length array feature of C
    reading_numbers( Max, array );
    most_present_number( Max, array );
    return 0;
}
```

a typical run of the code:

```
How much long the array will be?
4
Insert the numbers
1
Insert the numbers
2
Insert the numbers
3
Insert the numbers
2
This is the most present number 2 it is repeated 2 times
```